# Facebook API Group /feed limited to 10 items no matter the parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I query my owned secret Facebook group feed with a correct token and a limit parameter, say `/123456384920/feed?limit=50`, the Graph API only return 10 items and the paging doesn't work: the next "page" is returning no data (`data: []`).

It has worked several days ago, and my app isn't rate limited. The group has more than 10 items of course. I can't guess what is the problem.

Can anybody confirm it?

**Is there a more precise changelog for the Graph API (fixes & stuff) other than the [version upgrade changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)?**

Comment: sounds like a bug if it worked before: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1316646108368355/, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1796973007211974/, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1645827285730392/

Comment: Thank you both of you... Didn't even think of the bug tracker.