# Facebook Graph API: Next link returning empty data (group post)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I am using the Facebook Graph Api for get posts from my public group. It worked, but suddenly next link doesn't work now. I didn't change anything.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{groupID}/feed?access_token=myUserToken show me first ten posts in my group, but the link  in *paging -> next* show empty data. There's another ~ 30 posts

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Parameter *Limit* work only in interval 1 - 10 for me.

Any idea please? Thanks :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40379736/1427878

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug on facebook side, they are currently resolving it:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1796973007211974/

"Thank you for reporting this issue.

We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team.

Sergey

-November 2 at 6:53am"